# Drawing multiple charts using the same data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [**this**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4JhWEL4N7bxo3F9mzlPn?p=preview) example (will post all code below) I'm drawing two different charts using the same csv data.

What I basically want to know is if there's anything I'm doing "wrong" here or if there's a more efficient way of drawing the two charts in this way.

Here's all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<style>

body {
  margin:auto;
  width:850px;
  font:10px arial;
  padding:25px;
}
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding:3px;
  font:10px arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

Select Category: 
<select id="category">
  <option value=" 1">Category 1</option>
  <option value=" 2">Category 2</option>
</select> 

<!-- Chart -->
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>

let formatValue = d3.format(",.0f");

let margin = {top: 35, right: 35, bottom: 35, left: 35},
    width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let durations = 0;

let afterLoad = () => durations = 750;

// ===== Monthly bars init values =====

let x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

let g = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

// ===== Total bar init values =====

let totalG = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", (width/4) + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let xTotal = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, (width/4)]).padding(0.1),
    yTotal = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

let xAxisTotal = d3.axisBottom(xTotal),
    yAxisTotal = d3.axisLeft(yTotal);

totalG.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--xTotal")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
totalG.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--yTotal");

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "data.csv", d => d)
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, data) {

  if (error) throw error;

  var INT;

  // Event handlers
  d3.select("#category").on('change', update);

  update();

  function update() {

    INT = d3.select('#category').property('value');

    var totalSum = d3.sum(data, d => d["Category"  + INT])

    // ========= Monthly bars =========

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d["Category" + INT]) ]).nice();

    x.domain(data.map( d => d.month ));

    g.selectAll(".axis.axis--y").transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .call(yAxis);

    g.selectAll(".axis.axis--x").transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .call(xAxis);

    let bars = g.selectAll(".barEnter")
      .data(data, d => d.month);

    bars = bars
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "barEnter")
      .attr("fill","steelblue")
      .attr("x", d => x(d.month))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .merge(bars);

    bars.transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .attr("y", d => y(d["Category" + INT]))
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d["Category" + INT]))

    bars.exit().remove();

    // ========= Total bar =========

    yTotal.domain([0, totalSum]).nice();

    xTotal.domain(["Total"]);

    totalG.selectAll(".axis.axis--yTotal").transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .call(yAxisTotal);

    totalG.selectAll(".axis.axis--xTotal").transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .call(xAxisTotal);

    let totalBar = totalG.selectAll(".totalBar")
      .data(["empty"]); 

    totalBar = totalBar
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "totalBar")
      .attr("fill","#ccc")
      .attr("x", xTotal(["Total"]) )
      .attr("width", xTotal.bandwidth())
      .merge(totalBar)

    totalBar.transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .attr("y", yTotal(totalSum))
      .attr("height", height - yTotal(totalSum))

  } // End of update

  afterLoad()

} // End of ready

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall your code seems good, it's an idiomatic D3 and it doesn't have any major problem (like appending elements in a loop). I would put the two charts in a single SVG with different `<g>` elements, but that's a matter of personal choice (having two SVGs can be an advantage if you want, for instance, rearrange them in the HTML).

I'd suggest 3 changes, though:

1. You have just 1 CSV file. Therefore, you can drop the `d3.queue`, which is normally used to deal with **several** (that is, more than one) asynchronous tasks. Use a simple `d3.csv` instead:

   ```
   d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
       //etc...
   ```

   Edit: in the new D3 version 5, `d3.csv` uses promises. Therefore, the above snippet would be:

   ```
   d3.csv("data.csv").then(function (data) {
       //etc...
   ```
2. Don't use variables external to the function to define the behaviour of that function: it's hard to understand where the value comes from and harder to debug.

   Instead of that, pass those variables as arguments. In the case of your `update` function, pass the value of the dropdown:

   ```
   var category = d3.select('#category').property('value');

   d3.select("#category").on('change', function(){
       update(this.value)
   });

   update(category);

   function update(INT) {
       //etc...
   }
   ```
3. You don't need that `afterLoad` function... just change `durations` in the event handler!

   ```
   d3.select("#category").on('change', function(){
       durations = 750;
       update(this.value)
   });
   ```

Here is the updated Plunker with those changes: https://plnkr.co/edit/P5r3D7JRbhB9yv8dmwzg?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much! One small question though, in most of Mike Bostocks examples using csv he uses a `type` function and returns `d`, and there is no such function in your answer, in what scenarios should you use this function?

Comment: `d3.csv` always loads the values as strings, even if they are numbers. The row function is normally used to coercion (but not only).